# How to enable basic HTML/JSP syntax highlighting in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans-8

I installed the basic SE version of Netbeans 8.2 with the understanding that I could always manually add plugins as needed to cover any gaps between SE and the other versions.

Any idea which plugin I might add to get basic HTML/JSP syntax highlighting?  Not looking for any fancy WYSIWYG stuff, just plain code highlighting.

I wasn't keen to install the full-blown EE edition since I don't need Glassfish, Tomcat, EJB, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax  choose language (in this case JSP) then choose category and set color what you want [Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGQo3.png)

Comment: Well this is odd since I have a similar issue and can't find a way to add JSP as a language. Any hints appreciated.